# Selenium Actions Class copy past the Text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to copy and past the simple text give not desired output below is my code

```
public class practiceExample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:\\TopsAssignment\\SampleJavaExample\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        WebElement elm1 = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
        WebElement elm2 = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
        Actions cpypast = new Actions(driver); 


        Action write = cpypast.sendKeys(elm1, "Pratik").build();
        Action select  = cpypast.doubleClick(elm1).build();
        Action copy = cpypast.sendKeys(elm1, Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(elm1, "C").build();
        Action past = cpypast.sendKeys(elm2,Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(elm2,"V").build();
        write.perform();
        select.perform();
        copy.perform();
        past.perform();

        String str = elm2.getText();
        System.out.println(str);

        driver.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `Actions` Class when you can invoke the powerful `click()`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply will take care. works well with Robot class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with Robot class it works well

```
public class practiceExample2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:\\TopsAssignment\\SampleJavaExample\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    WebElement elm1 = driver.findElement(By.name("firstname"));
    String test = elm1.getText();
    System.out.println(test);


    WebElement elm2 = driver.findElement(By.name("lastname"));


    Actions cpypast = new Actions(driver);
    cpypast.sendKeys(elm1,"Pratik").doubleClick().contextClick().build().perform();

    Robot rb = new Robot();
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    Actions cpypast1 = new Actions(driver);

    cpypast1.contextClick(elm2).build().perform();

    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    String str = elm2.getText();
    System.out.println(str);

    driver.close();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to select the text value successfully, and the problem is only to 'Copy' and 'Paste', you might find this solution useful-

Problem line:

```
Action copy = cpypast.sendKeys(elm1, Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(elm1, "C").build();
```

Instead use this code:

```
Action copy = cpypast.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("C").build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion